# react-livechat doesn't work with react-snapshot

Tags: reactjs

I've been using `react-snapshot` to do server side rendering of my site. I'm using it in production but not on my localhost.  I use it so I can inject my meta keywords/description on my product pages.

Today I added a LiveChat bot (from LiveChatInc) via their `react-livechat` component.  The implementation is simple:

```
import LiveChat from 'react-livechat';

<LiveChat license={1234567} />
```

This seems to work just fine on my localhost (where I'm not using react-snapshot) but not on my production site.  When I remove `react-snapshot` from production, it works just fine.

**THE ERROR**

So it looks the code above adds, amongst other code, the following line:

```
<script src="https://secure.livechatinc.com/licence/null/v2/get_dynamic_config.js"></script>
```

You can see from this line that the license is `null`.  So, I'm guessing it's something with `react-snapshot` that prevents this code `<LiveChat license={1234567} />` from grabbing the correct code from LiveChat.

The other method of implementation is by inserting the following code near the `</body>` tag.  But this method also produces the same error.

```
<!-- Start of LiveChat (www.livechatinc.com) code -->
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.__lc = window.__lc || {};
  window.__lc.license = 1234567;
  (function() {
    var lc = document.createElement('script'); lc.type = 'text/javascript'; lc.async = true;
    lc.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://' : 'http://') + 'cdn.livechatinc.com/tracking.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(lc, s);
  })();
</script>
<noscript>
<a href="https://www.livechatinc.com/chat-with/1234567/" rel="nofollow">Chat with us</a>,
powered by <a href="https://www.livechatinc.com/?welcome" rel="noopener nofollow" target="_blank">LiveChat</a>
</noscript>
<!-- End of LiveChat code -->
```

**THE SOLUTION**

So I finally got this to work.  I actually tried several pre-rendering solutions (react-snapshot, react-snap, react-static) and none of them implemented `react-livechat` correctly.  So then I started thinking that maybe it was the way I was implementing it.  But, I implemented it according to the docs so I really don't know why it didn't work.  What I ended up doing was using `react-loadable` as such:

```
const LoadableLiveChat = Loadable({
  loader: () => import('react-livechat'),
  loading: () => '<div>Loading</div>'
});

<LoadableLiveChat license={1234567} />
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Could you give a link to your staging area or something like that on which you have deployed (and broken) version with react-snapshot used? Hard to give any advice without seeing that setup "in action".

Comment: I added more error information and also the URL to my site.  Thanks for helping out.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't get back to you sooner. Glad you have figured it out!